# VM Arguments: Retrieve correctly and programmatically

Tags: java, jvm, arguments

I am attempting to programmatically retrieve the VM arguments from within a Java application.

---

After doing some research, I came across what seemed to be a perfect solution:

```
ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getInputArguments();
```

However, when the content of an argument contains a space character, the argument is split and only up to that space character is present in the list.

With the example VM arguments `-Xmx1024mb -javaagent:"C:/Users/Thompson Main/Documents/app.jar"`, the following list is returned:

```
[0] -> -Xmx1024mb
[1] -> -javaagent:C:/Users/Thompson
[2] -> Main/Documents/app.jar
[3] -> -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
```

The second VM argument is cut off due to containing a unavoidable space, and I cannot assume that all of my users lack a space character in file paths.  This bug renders ManagementFactory and RuntimeMXBean useless in my opinion.

---

I have done more research, but I haven't been able to locate an alternate, successful way to retrieve VM arguments in their entirety in Java 6 (thanks Jean-Philippe for letting me know it works in Java 7).

What is another way to acquire VM arguments from within an application?

Comment: Out of interest, what's at index `[2]`?

Comment: @GregKopff My bad, there's actually objects at indices 2 and 3 which I accidentally omitted from the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a JDK bug, corrected in JDK 7 : [RuntimeMXBean.getInputArguments() doesn't handle arguments with spaces properly](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug;jsessionid=f84d44729bd8affffffffeb9b87963e2d752?bug_id=6459832).

*Good solution* : upgrade to Java 7.

*Ugly solution* : reconstruct the parameters, but it's going to bed awful :(

Comment: Thanks, but I unfortunately will not be upgrading to Java 7 because it has very low penetration among my application's user base.  Luckily, the arguments I need to analyze all will end in .jar, so I can reconstruct it if the current line starts with an argument (like "-javaagent:") but doesn't end in ".jar".  Accepted answer.